# how to copy highlighted text with mouse middle (second) button in nvim

Tags: neovim

New to nvim, but one feature I would really benefit from is to do the following:

Go to a portion of the screen (in nvim or elsewhere). Highlight some text with the mouse (using the first button).
Then move to the nvim window and use the second button (middle) button of the mouse, or Shift-Insert key to paste it.

I have been so far using the following:

```
let g:clipboard = {
  \   'name': 'xclip-clipman',
  \   'copy': {
  \      '+': 'xclip -selection clipboard',
  \      '*': 'xclip -selection clipboard',
  \    },
  \   'paste': {
  \      '+': 'xclip -selection clipboard -o',
  \      '*': 'xclip -selection clipboard -o',
  \   },
  \   'cache_enabled': 1,
  \ }

set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

but I was wondering if there is a simple way to do this. For one, it does not seem to me to be able to copy to clipboard from something like xterm. And I am looking for a simpler option such as the one I outlined above. Any suggestions?

Separately, but related, is there a way to flush out the register?

Thanks for any help and suggestions!